# Collection View Content are not in Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on CollectionView where I have SupplementryView as well.
Everything works fine but contents are not in the frame in random cell.

Below are[image] screenshots

[image]

I have tired to reset lay of cell & content view in UICOllectioViewCell subclass below but no effect

```
[self layoutSubviews];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

and

```
[self.contentView layoutSubviews];
[self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

Please suggest how to fix this issue. Any idea would be great.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your constraints? o.O

Comment: How did you position the elements  ? Did u use auto layout ?

Comment: no, I am not using Auto layout code.

Comment: Show the code on how you created the elements. You have to use constraints to make them stick at the place you want.